# Successful formSubmit taking to error page 404

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a simple modal feedback form which pops out on click of button from my main page.I passes my form values to controller and insert the values using Hibernate.After successful insertion of DB values, I want my modal to close with some custom message to show it to the user.But my problem is, its redirecting me to the another page error.jsp with 404 error.Also looks like its not returning the ajax call as successful. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.
Please help.
Below is my controller, DAO, JS,JSP code

JSP code

```
          <p><button id="modal_open" class="inner rotate">Site   Feedback</button></p>

          <div id="modal_wrapper">
          <div id="modal_window">

          <div style="text-align: right;"><a id="modal_close" href="#">close   <b>X</b></a></div>

          <p><Strong>We'd love your feedback.</Strong><br></p>

          <p>Your feedback will help us improve your experience. To protect your privacy, please do not enter personal or account information.</p>

          <form id="modal_feedback" method="POST" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8" >
          Your Name :<br>
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value=""><span></span><br>
          <div class="feedback">
          <div class="feedbackCl" >
          <input id="overall_0" name="overall" id="overall" type="radio" value="1" tabindex="0" aria-describedby="o1-l">
          <label for="overall_0" class="labelClass">
          <span class="sight">— —</span>
          <span class="screen_reader" id="o1-l">Poor</span>
         </label>
       </div>
       <div class="feedbackCl">
    <input id="overall_1" name="overall"  id="overall" type="radio" value="2" tabindex="0" aria-describedby="o2-l">
    <label for="overall_1" class="labelClass">
      <span class="sight">—</span>
      <span class="screen_reader" id="o2-l">Fair</span>
    </label>

  </div>
  <div class="feedbackCl">
    <input id="overall_2" name="overall" id="overall" type="radio" value="3" tabindex="0" aria-describedby="o3-l">
    <label for="overall_2" class="labelClass">
      <span class="sight">+ —</span>
      <span class="screen_reader" id="o3-l">Good</span>
    </label>
  </div>
   <div class="feedbackCl">
    <input id="overall_3" name="overall" id="overall" type="radio" value="4" tabindex="0" aria-describedby="o4-l">
    <label for="overall_3" class="labelClass">
      <span class="sight">+</span>
      <span class="screen_reader" id="o4-l">Very Good</span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="feedbackCl">
    <input id="overall_4" name="overall" id="overall" type="radio" value="5" tabindex="0" aria-describedby="o5-l">
    <label for="overall_4" class="labelClass">
      <span class="sight">+ +</span>
      <span class="screen_reader" id="o5-l">Excellent</span>
    </label>
  </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <span><br></span><br>
  <textarea style="overflow-x: hidden;" id="gBann" name="message" maxlength="1000" rows="4" cols="80" placeholder="How can we improve our site? Please share your suggestions." onKeyUp="toCount('gBann','uBann','{CHAR} characters left',1000);" ></textarea><br>
  <span id="uBann" class="minitext" style="text-align: right;">1000 characters left</span><br> 
  <input type="submit" name="feedbackForm" class="buttonFb button1" value="Submit" id="submit_btn">
</form>
```

JS code

```
        document.getElementById("modal_feedback").addEventListener("submit",    function(e) {
        var form = this;
        var name = form.name.value;
        var rating = form.overall.value;
        var msg = form.message.value;
        if(name == "") {
          alert("Please enter your Name");
          form.name.focus();
          e.preventDefault();
          } else if(rating == "") {
          alert("Please select a rating");
          form.overall[0].focus();
          e.preventDefault();
          } else if(msg == "") {
          alert("Please enter your comment in the Message box");
          form.message.focus();
          e.preventDefault();
          }
          $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "feedbackData.htm?ratingId="+rating+"&msg="+msg,
             success: function(response) {
             if(response == 'Y'){
             $('#contact_form').html("<div id='message'></div>");
             $('#message').html("<h2>FeedbackForm Submitted!</h2>")
             .append("<p>We will be in touch soon.</p>")
             .hide()
             .fadeIn(1500, function() {
                 $('#message').append("<img id='checkmark' src='images/icon_check.png' />");
               });
              }
             }
           });
          return false;

      }, false);

         FeedbackController code

         @Controller
         public class FeedbackController {

        @Autowired
        private FeedbackService feedbackService;

        private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FeedbackController.class);

        @RequestMapping(value = "/feedbackData")
        public @ResponseBody String getFeedbackData(String ratingId, String msg) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
         System.out.println("Inside FeedbackController..");
        try{
           feedbackService.updateFeedback(ratingId,msg);
           return "Y";
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
          logger.error("Exception in Login :" + e);
          return "N";
         }
       }

     }
```

FeedbackDAO implementation

```
      @Repository("feedbackDao")
      public class FeedbackDaoImpl implements FeedbackDao{

      @Autowired
      private SessionFactory sessionFactory;    

      @Override
      public int insertFeedback(String ratingId, String msg) {
      int status = 0;

      Session sess = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        try {
            tx = sess.beginTransaction();
            Feedback fbObj = new Feedback();
            fbObj.setFbRatingId(Integer.parseInt(ratingId));
            fbObj.setFbSuggestion(msg);
            fbObj.setFbTopicId(null);
            fbObj.setUserInfo("");
            sess.save(fbObj);
            tx.commit();
            status  = 1;
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception in feedback record :" + e);
            if (tx != null) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
        } finally {
            sess.close();
        }        
     return status;
}

 }
```

Error Trace

```
         Inside FeedbackController..
         Hibernate: insert into feedback (fb_rating_id, fb_suggestion,  fb_topic_id, user_info) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
         Apr 05, 2017 12:12:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
             SEVERE:Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
             javax.servlet.ServletException:      File [/WEB-INF/views/error.jsp] not found
            at                    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.handleMissingResource(JspServlet.java:418)
            at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at              org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:716)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:584)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:523)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:229)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1060)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:798)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:563)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1104)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1519)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1475)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

       Apr 05, 2017 12:12:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
       SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [tdp] in context with path              [/TDP] threw exception [File [/WEB-INF/views/error.jsp] not found] with root cause
       javax.servlet.ServletException: File [/WEB-INF/views/error.jsp] not found
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.handleMissingResource(JspServlet.java:418)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
```

Comment: check the url .htm try .html

Comment: changing to .html would not help. cause URL pattern defined is htm only.